# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException index 0 requested with a size of 0 Other answers don't work

Tags: android, cursor

I've read all the other pages on this error here and none of the solutions seem to work for me. Any help is appreciated. I have an activity that lets the user insert as much data as they want. It is then saved into SQL then the user can select the specific set of data they just saved. When i try to begin a new one now it throws this error.

```
07-15 16:43:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(320): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 16:43:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(320): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
07-15 16:43:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
07-15 16:43:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
07-15 16:43:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
07-15 16:43:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at com.rivers.gt5protuner.CrAETune$LoadContacts.onPostExecute(CrAETune.java:261)
07-15 16:43:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at com.rivers.gt5protuner.CrAETune$LoadContacts.onPostExecute(CrAETune.java:1)
07-15 16:43:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
07-15 16:43:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
07-15 16:43:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
07-15 16:43:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-15 16:43:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 16:43:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5233)
07-15 16:43:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 16:43:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 16:43:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
07-15 16:43:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
07-15 16:43:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 16:48:06.972: I/Process(320): Sending signal. PID: 320 SIG: 9
```

From this code

```
public class CrAETune extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

 private long rowID; 
 private EditText caret,lapet,trket,ppet,tyet,rh1,rh2,sr1,sr2,de1,de2,dc1,dc2,ar1,ar2,c1,c2,t1,t2,bb1,bb2,li1,li2,la1,la2,lb1,lb2,df1,df2,g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7,gf,ts,hp,tq,lb,mil,rpm,parts,comments,combo,sorttime,sortpp;
 String a,b,c,message,pps,tys,rh1s,rh2s,sr1s,sr2s,de1s,de2s,dc1s,dc2s,ar1s,ar2s,c1s,c2s,t1s,t2s,bb1s,bb2s,li1s,li2s,la1s,la2s,lb1s,lb2s,df1s,df2s,g1s,g2s,g3s,g4s,g5s,g6s,g7s,gfs,tss,hps,tqs,lbs,mils,rpms,partss,commentss;

 Button paste;



   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 


   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.personalsetup);
      caret = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcartype);
      lapet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editlaptime);
      trket = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittracktype);
      ppet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editperfpoints);
      tyet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittires);
      rh1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editrh1);
      rh2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editrh2);
      sr1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editsr1);
      sr2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editsr2);
      de1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editde1);
      de2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editde2);
      dc1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editdc1);
      dc2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editdc2);
      ar1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editar1);
      ar2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editar2);
       c1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editc1);
       c2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editc2);
       t1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editt1);
       t2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editt2);
      bb1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editbb1);
      bb2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editbb2); 
      li1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editli1);
      li2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editli2);
      la1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editla1);
      la2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editla2);
      lb1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editlb1);
      lb2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editlb2);
      df1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editdf1);
      df2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editdf2);
       g1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editgear1);
       g2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editgear2);
       g3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editgear3);
       g4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editgear4);
       g5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editgear5);
       g6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editgear6);
       g7 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editgear7);
       gf = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editgf);
       ts = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittop);
       hp = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edithp);
       tq = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittq);
       lb = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editweight);
       mil = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editmiles);
       rpm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editrpm);
       parts = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editparts);
       comments = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editcomments);
       combo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editcombo);
       sorttime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editsorttime);
       sortpp = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editsortpp);
       paste = (Button)findViewById(R.id.newpasteBtn);
       paste.setOnClickListener(this);





       Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 


              if (extras != null)
      {
         rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
         caret.setText(extras.getString("car"));  
         lapet.setText(extras.getString("lap"));  
         trket.setText(extras.getString("trk"));  
         ppet.setText(extras.getString("pp"));
         tyet.setText(extras.getString("ty"));
         rh1.setText(extras.getString("rh1"));
         rh2.setText(extras.getString("rh2"));
         sr1.setText(extras.getString("sr1"));
         sr2.setText(extras.getString("sr2"));
         de1.setText(extras.getString("de1"));
         de2.setText(extras.getString("de2"));
         dc1.setText(extras.getString("dc1"));
         dc2.setText(extras.getString("dc2"));
         ar1.setText(extras.getString("ar1"));
         ar2.setText(extras.getString("ar2"));
         c1.setText(extras.getString("c1"));
         c2.setText(extras.getString("c2"));
         t1.setText(extras.getString("t1"));
         t2.setText(extras.getString("t2"));
         bb1.setText(extras.getString("bb1"));
         bb2.setText(extras.getString("bb2"));
         li1.setText(extras.getString("li1"));
         li2.setText(extras.getString("li2"));
         la1.setText(extras.getString("la1"));
         la2.setText(extras.getString("la2"));
         lb1.setText(extras.getString("lb1"));
         lb2.setText(extras.getString("lb2"));
         df1.setText(extras.getString("df1"));
         df2.setText(extras.getString("df2"));
         g1.setText(extras.getString("g1"));
         g2.setText(extras.getString("g2"));
         g3.setText(extras.getString("g3"));
         g4.setText(extras.getString("g4"));
         g5.setText(extras.getString("g5"));
         g6.setText(extras.getString("g6"));
         g7.setText(extras.getString("g7"));
         gf.setText(extras.getString("gf"));
         ts.setText(extras.getString("ts"));
         hp.setText(extras.getString("hp"));
         tq.setText(extras.getString("tq"));
         lb.setText(extras.getString("lb"));
         mil.setText(extras.getString("mil"));
         rpm.setText(extras.getString("rpm"));
         parts.setText(extras.getString("parts"));

         comments.setText(extras.getString("comments"));

         }

      Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.newsaveBtn);
      saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
          {
              if (caret.getText().length() != 0)
                 {
                    AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                       new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                       {
                          @Override
                          protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                          {
                             saveContact();
                             return null;
                          }

                          @Override
                          protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                          {
                             finish();
                          }
                       }; 

                    saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
                 }

                 else
                 {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(CrAETune.this);
                    alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                    alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                    alert.show();
                 }
              } 
         });
       }


   @Override
   protected void onResume()
   {
      super.onResume();
      new LoadContacts().execute(rowID);
   } 

   private class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> 
   {
      CrDbCon dbConnector = new CrDbCon(CrAETune.this);

      @Override
      protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params)
      {
         dbConnector.open();
         return dbConnector.getOneContact(params[0]);
      } 

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
      {
         super.onPostExecute(result);


         // get the column index for each data item
         int nameIndex = result.getColumnIndex("car");
         int capIndex = result.getColumnIndex("lap");
         int codeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("trk");
         int newIndex = result.getColumnIndex("pp");
         int epicIndex = result.getColumnIndex("ty");
         int aIndex = result.getColumnIndex("rh1");
         int bIndex = result.getColumnIndex("rh2");
         int cIndex = result.getColumnIndex("sr1");
         int dIndex = result.getColumnIndex("sr2");
         int eIndex = result.getColumnIndex("de1");
         int fIndex = result.getColumnIndex("de2");
         int dc1Index = result.getColumnIndex("dc1");
         int dc2Index = result.getColumnIndex("dc2");
         int ar1Index = result.getColumnIndex("ar1");
         int ar2Index = result.getColumnIndex("ar2");
         int kIndex = result.getColumnIndex("c1");
         int lIndex = result.getColumnIndex("c2");
         int mIndex = result.getColumnIndex("t1");
         int nIndex = result.getColumnIndex("t2");
         int rIndex = result.getColumnIndex("li1");
         int qIndex = result.getColumnIndex("li2");
         int sIndex = result.getColumnIndex("la1");
         int tIndex = result.getColumnIndex("la2");
         int bbtIndex = result.getColumnIndex("bb1");
         int bbsIndex = result.getColumnIndex("bb2");
         int uIndex = result.getColumnIndex("lb1");
         int vIndex = result.getColumnIndex("lb2");
         int wIndex = result.getColumnIndex("df1");
         int xIndex = result.getColumnIndex("df2");
         int yIndex = result.getColumnIndex("g1");
         int zIndex = result.getColumnIndex("g2");
         int aaIndex = result.getColumnIndex("g3");
         int bbIndex = result.getColumnIndex("g4");
         int ccIndex = result.getColumnIndex("g5");
         int ddIndex = result.getColumnIndex("g6");
         int eeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("g7");
         int ffIndex = result.getColumnIndex("gf");
         int topsIndex = result.getColumnIndex("ts");
         int horsepIndex = result.getColumnIndex("hp");
         int torqIndex = result.getColumnIndex("tq");
         int lbsIndex = result.getColumnIndex("lb");
         int mileIndex = result.getColumnIndex("mil");
         int rpmsIndex = result.getColumnIndex("rpm");
         int partIndex = result.getColumnIndex("parts");
         int commentsIndex = result.getColumnIndex("comments");



         caret.setText(result.getString(nameIndex));
         lapet.setText(result.getString(capIndex));
         trket.setText(result.getString(codeIndex));
         ppet.setText(result.getString(newIndex));
         tyet.setText(result.getString(epicIndex));
         rh1.setText(result.getString(aIndex));
         rh2.setText(result.getString(bIndex));
         sr1.setText(result.getString(cIndex));
         sr2.setText(result.getString(dIndex));
         de1.setText(result.getString(eIndex));
         de2.setText(result.getString(fIndex));
         dc1.setText(result.getString(dc1Index));
         dc2.setText(result.getString(dc2Index));
         ar1.setText(result.getString(ar1Index));
         ar2.setText(result.getString(ar2Index));
         c1.setText(result.getString(kIndex));
         c2.setText(result.getString(lIndex));
         t1.setText(result.getString(mIndex));
         t2.setText(result.getString(nIndex));
         bb1.setText(result.getString(bbtIndex));
         bb2.setText(result.getString(bbsIndex));
         li2.setText(result.getString(qIndex));
         li1.setText(result.getString(rIndex));
         la1.setText(result.getString(sIndex));
         la2.setText(result.getString(tIndex));
         lb1.setText(result.getString(uIndex));
         lb2.setText(result.getString(vIndex));
         df1.setText(result.getString(wIndex));
         df2.setText(result.getString(xIndex));
         g1.setText(result.getString(yIndex));
         g2.setText(result.getString(zIndex));
         g3.setText(result.getString(aaIndex));
         g4.setText(result.getString(bbIndex));
         g5.setText(result.getString(ccIndex));
         g6.setText(result.getString(ddIndex));
         g7.setText(result.getString(eeIndex));
         gf.setText(result.getString(ffIndex));
         ts.setText(result.getString(topsIndex));
         hp.setText(result.getString(horsepIndex));
         tq.setText(result.getString(torqIndex));
         lb.setText(result.getString(lbsIndex));
         mil.setText(result.getString(mileIndex));
         rpm.setText(result.getString(rpmsIndex));
         parts.setText(result.getString(partIndex));
         comments.setText(result.getString(commentsIndex));



         result.close();
         dbConnector.close();
      }
   } 

    private void saveContact() 
       {
          CrDbCon dbConnector = new CrDbCon(this);

          if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
          {
              dbConnector.insertContact(
                      caret.getText().toString(),//1
                      lapet.getText().toString(),
                      trket.getText().toString(),
                      ppet.getText().toString(),
                      tyet.getText().toString(),//5
                      rh1.getText().toString(),
                      rh2.getText().toString(),
                      sr1.getText().toString(),
                      sr2.getText().toString(),
                      de1.getText().toString(),//10
                      de2.getText().toString(),
                      dc1.getText().toString(),
                      dc2.getText().toString(),
                      ar1.getText().toString(),
                      ar2.getText().toString(),//15
                      c1.getText().toString(),
                      c2.getText().toString(),
                      t1.getText().toString(),
                      t2.getText().toString(),
                      bb1.getText().toString(),//20
                      bb2.getText().toString(),
                      li1.getText().toString(),
                      li2.getText().toString(),
                      la1.getText().toString(),
                      la2.getText().toString(),
                      lb1.getText().toString(),
                      lb2.getText().toString(),
                      df1.getText().toString(),
                      df2.getText().toString(),
                      g1.getText().toString(),
                      g2.getText().toString(),
                      g3.getText().toString(),//30
                      g4.getText().toString(),
                      g5.getText().toString(),
                      g6.getText().toString(),
                      g7.getText().toString(),
                      gf.getText().toString(),//35
                      ts.getText().toString(),
                      hp.getText().toString(),
                      tq.getText().toString(),
                      lb.getText().toString(),
                      mil.getText().toString(),//40
                      rpm.getText().toString(),
                      parts.getText().toString(),
                      comments.getText().toString(),

                      combo.getText().toString(),
                      sorttime.getText().toString(),
                      sortpp.getText().toString());//43
          }
          else
          {
             dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
                caret.getText().toString(),
                lapet.getText().toString(), 
                trket.getText().toString(),
                ppet.getText().toString(),
                tyet.getText().toString(),
                rh1.getText().toString(),
                  rh2.getText().toString(),
                  sr1.getText().toString(),
                  sr2.getText().toString(),
                  de1.getText().toString(),//10
                  de2.getText().toString(),
                  dc1.getText().toString(),
                  dc2.getText().toString(),
                  ar1.getText().toString(),
                  ar2.getText().toString(),//15
                  c1.getText().toString(),
                  c2.getText().toString(),
                  t1.getText().toString(),
                  t2.getText().toString(),
                  bb1.getText().toString(),//20
                  bb2.getText().toString(),
                  li1.getText().toString(),
                  li2.getText().toString(),
                  la1.getText().toString(),
                  la2.getText().toString(),
                  lb1.getText().toString(),
                  lb2.getText().toString(),
                  df1.getText().toString(),
                  df2.getText().toString(),
                  g1.getText().toString(),
                  g2.getText().toString(),
                  g3.getText().toString(),//30
                  g4.getText().toString(),
                  g5.getText().toString(),
                  g6.getText().toString(),
                  g7.getText().toString(),
                  gf.getText().toString(),//35
                  ts.getText().toString(),
                  hp.getText().toString(),
                  tq.getText().toString(),
                  lb.getText().toString(),
                  mil.getText().toString(),//40
                  rpm.getText().toString(),
                  parts.getText().toString(),
                  comments.getText().toString(),

                  combo.getText().toString(),
                  sorttime.getText().toString(),
                  sortpp.getText().toString());




   }


   }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.newpasteBtn:

            Intent awee = new Intent(CrAETune.this, GoPro.class);
            startActivity(awee);
            break;
         case R.id.deleteBtn:
                deleteContact();
                break;
             case R.id.shareBtn:
                 getstrings();
                 String message = "Hey I just used my "
                 +a
                 +" to post a "
                 +b
                 +" on "
                 +c
                 +" with this setup saved with my GT5 PRO Tuner App from DarkLionRacing"
                 +'\n'
                 +" Performance Points "
                 +pps
                 + '\n' 
                 +" Tires were "
                 +tys
                 +'\n'+" and the parts settings go like this "+" Ride Height "+rh1s+" / "+rh2s
                 +'\n'+" Spring Rate "+sr1s+" / "+sr2s
                 +'\n'+" Damper(EXT)"+de1s+" / "+de2s
                 +'\n'+" Damper(COMP "+dc1s+" / "+dc2s
                 +'\n'+" AntiRoll Bar "+ar1s+" / "+ar2s
                 +'\n'+" Camber "+c1s+" / "+c2s
                 +'\n'+" Toe "+t1s+" / "+t2s
                 +'\n'+" Brake Bias "+bb1s+" / "+bb2s
                 +'\n'+" LSD Init "+li1s+" / "+li2s
                 +'\n'+" LSD Accel "+la1s+" / "+la2s
                 +'\n'+" LSD Braking "+lb1s+" / "+lb2s
                 +'\n'+" Downforce "+df1s+" / "+df2s
                 +'\n'+" Gears "
                 +'\n'+g1s
                 +'\n'+g2s
                 +'\n'+g3s
                 +'\n'+g4s
                 +'\n'+g5s
                 +'\n'+g6s
                 +'\n'+g7s
                 +'\n'+gfs
                 +'\n'+" Top Speed "
                 +'\n'+tss
                 +'\n'+" Horse power "+"  "+hps
                 +'\n'+" Torque "+"  "+tqs
                 +'\n'+" Weight "+"  "+lbs
                 +'\n'+" Distance on the motor "+" "+mils
                 +'\n'+" RPM "+" "+rpms
                 +'\n'+" The parts I installed were "+" "+partss
                 +'\n'+" "+commentss
                 +" I bet you'll love it! "

                 ;

                 Intent golk = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                 golk.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL," " );
                 golk.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Check Out This Setup!");
                 golk.setType("text/plain");
                 golk.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
                 startActivity(golk);
                 break;
             case R.id.copyBtn:

                Intent awe = new Intent(CrAETune.this, GoPro.class);
                startActivity(awe);
                break;}

          }
         private void deleteContact()
           {

              AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(CrAETune.this);

              alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle); 
              alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage); 

              alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
                 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                 {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
                    {
                       final CrDbCon dbConnector = 
                          new CrDbCon(CrAETune.this);

                       AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask =
                          new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>()
                          {
                             @Override
                             protected Object doInBackground(Long... params)
                             {
                                dbConnector.deleteContact(params[0]); 
                                return null;
                             } 

                             @Override
                             protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
                             {
                                finish(); 
                             }
                          };

                       deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });               
                    }
                 }
              );

    }
    private void getstrings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        a=caret.getText().toString();
        b=lapet.getText().toString();
        c=trket.getText().toString();
        pps=ppet.getText().toString();
        tys=tyet.getText().toString();
        rh1s=rh1.getText().toString();
        rh2s=rh2.getText().toString();
        sr1s=sr1.getText().toString();
        sr2s=sr2.getText().toString();
        de1s=de1.getText().toString();
        de2s=de2.getText().toString();
        dc1s=dc1.getText().toString();
        dc2s=dc2.getText().toString();
        ar1s=ar1.getText().toString();
        ar2s=ar2.getText().toString();
        c1s=c1.getText().toString();
        c2s=c2.getText().toString();
        t1s=t1.getText().toString();
        t2s=t2.getText().toString();
        bb1s=bb1.getText().toString();
        bb2s=bb2.getText().toString();
        li1s=li1.getText().toString();
        li2s=li2.getText().toString();
        la1s=la1.getText().toString();
        la2s=la2.getText().toString();
        lb1s=lb1.getText().toString();
        lb2s=lb2.getText().toString();
        df1s=df1.getText().toString();
        df2s=df2.getText().toString();
        g1s=g1.getText().toString();
        g2s=g2.getText().toString();
        g3s=g3.getText().toString();
        g4s=g4.getText().toString();
        g5s=g5.getText().toString();
        g6s=g6.getText().toString();
        g7s=g7.getText().toString();
        gfs=gf.getText().toString();
        tss=ts.getText().toString();
        hps=hp.getText().toString();
        tqs=tq.getText().toString();
        lbs=lb.getText().toString();
        mils=mil.getText().toString();
        rpms=rpm.getText().toString();
        partss=parts.getText().toString();
        commentss=comments.getText().toString();
    }


    }
```

Comment: What's on the 261 line in your `CrAETune` java file?

Comment: int nameIndex = result.getColumnIndex("car");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the

```
result.moveToFirst();
```

statement before trying to get the column indexes for your data items.

So your method should be like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (result != null && result.moveToFirst()) {

         // get the column index for each data item
         int nameIndex = result.getColumnIndex("car");
         int capIndex = result.getColumnIndex("lap");
         // ... all the other lines go here
         parts.setText(result.getString(partIndex));
         comments.setText(result.getString(commentsIndex));
    }

    result.close();
    dbConnector.close();
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks mate. I had actually changed it to read   result.moveToFirst(); but hadnt added anything else. Thanks again